# Ways of making python socket recv faster?

Tags: python-sockets

I have a project that is extremely latency sensitive and have been using sockets for quite some time. However, upon timing the individual parts of my code to optimize it, I saw that the .recv function is inconsistent in time and is too slow for my case. The average amount of time is approximately .05 seconds with a rough range of .5 seconds to .0005 seconds. Ideally, the number should be as close to 1 ms (.001) as possible with minimal variation. I've tried setting TCP_nodelay and setblocking(False), both of which gave very minimal improvement. I should mention that I am sending less than 128 bytes to one device and 1 byte to the other one, so very small packets. I have set the correct buffersize for each recv. I would prefer to stay away from UDP if possible. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Jah-On

Comment: How about lowering the buffer size to 128KB?

Comment: @George Y, I have the appropriate buffer or MTU size set for each receive. Thanks for your thought!